# How can I override the onclick behavior of IonBackButton

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic-react

How can I override the onclick behavior of an `IonBackButton`? I was able to add my own listener but I cannot figure how to prevent the default listener from firing. I plan to warn the user if they have unsaved data.

Comment: Check this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/hardware-back-button

Comment: I don't think that's possible but you can just create your own back button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replying from your comment on my last post, I'm not sure if I understand what you truly want but in my opinion you can just make the back button disabled for the user as long as the condition is not true. And once the condition is met, change the disabled to false.

In html,

```
<ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button disabled="btnCondition"></ion-back-button>
</ion-buttons>
```

In .ts,

```
btnCondition:boolean = true; //declare

yourfunction() {
    //Whatever code you want
    if(yourcondition==true){
      btnCondition = false; //This will make the back button to work
    }
    elseif(yourcondition==false) {
      //Do anything
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a custom back button using `NavContext` used in `IonBackButton`.
This is how `IonBackButton` is implemented. https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/main/packages/react/src/components/navigation/IonBackButton.tsx

`onClick` of `IonBackButton` is implemented as below

```js
(e: React.MouseEvent) => {
    const { defaultHref, routerAnimation } = this.props
    if (this.context.hasIonicRouter()) {
      e.stopPropagation()
      this.context.goBack(defaultHref, routerAnimation)
    } else if (defaultHref !== undefined) {
      window.location.href = defaultHref
    }
  }
```

and this is a simple custom `BackButton` using `NavContext`

```js
import { NavContext } from "@ionic/react"
import React, { useContext } from "react"

interface IBackButtonProps {
  defaultHref?: string
}

export const BackButton: React.FC<IBackButtonProps> = function BackButton({
  defaultHref = "/",
}) {
  const navContext = useContext(NavContext)
  const onClick = (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
    if (navContext.hasIonicRouter()) {
      e.stopPropagation()
      navContext.goBack(defaultHref, undefined)
    } else if (defaultHref !== undefined) {
      window.location.href = defaultHref
    }
  }

  return <button onClick={onClick} style={{ width: 48, height: 48 }} />
}
```

Be sure that there can be some unexpected behaviors as the above component only implements `onClick` event. It does not use `IonBackButtonInner` which is the inner component of `IonBackButton`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ionic 4/5, you can just set it like this,

```
<ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button defaultHref="home"></ion-back-button>
</ion-buttons>
```

If it doesn't work, you can also use ion-icon and put click function to navigate to other page.

Comment: That changes the url but it still navigates. I want to prevent the navigation from occurring if a condition is true.

Comment: Is there an easy way to make a custom back button that looks identical on iOS and Android?

Answer (score 0):

You can also overwrite the subscription of the back button for example in app.component.ts

```
  private backButtonEvent() {
    this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(1, () => {
      console.log('BACK BUTTON TRIGGERED');
      this.yourFunction();
    });
  }
```

If you just want to prevent any action in your current ts file:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.backButtonSubscription = this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(9999, () => {});
  }

ionViewWillLeave() {
  this.backButtonSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```